# How to create map render based on noise heightmap data

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, heightmap

I'm working actually on a endless map based on a Noise who generate a Height map. I did all the mash generator to display chunks and simple texture (a pixel color for each "height" on data):

[image]

Now, I want to generate a large view with "paper map" style, I tried to flat the chunk (look like a plane) but it look like full of pixel (I generate less data for large view)

[image]

I want something like this but I really don't know how to do it ? ( I got some brush for Photoshop)
[image]

- Do I need to generate nicer texture (probably larger, I have only 1px/data so it's hard to be more smooth), If yes: Can I use sub-sprites (like brush) into a texture ?
- Do I need to use some shader instead of texture ? And do the render only here ?
- OR I may only display the background (and the lakes ?) into the texture and add real sprites (for mountain or tree) into the world at the good position ?
- For the water: Do I have to generate a shape by looking every pixel on it and smooth the border ? Or Can i do this part only on the rendering (texture or shader) ?

**UPDATE** I'm closing this issue to move it into Game Development:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/165927/unity3d-how-to-create-flat-map-render-based-on-endless-noise-data

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: GAME DEVELOPMENT

Comment: Instead of essentially opening a duplicate question, if you want to move the question to another stack exchange, then you need to [request question migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: @Pikalek, I did try, but I cannot found how to move it to game dev :/

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/228147) in the link I posted covers the process. In your case, since you have less than 3,000 rep, you can flag & request migration. I've already flagged it, so now it's a matter of having the mods sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw land layer using textures.
2. Draw water on top (hardest will be those edges, maybe simplify that).
3. Draw grass trees from top to bottom (randomly with fixed seed in concerned areas, more probability if dense).
4. Your mountains are somewhat overkill, but would have to be drawn from top to bottom.

Maybe see how Heroes of Might and Magic III does a nice map: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V61Hd_Xt40A

Comment: Thank a lots about your reply but I was more asking about the technology to do it. If I understand well we think I must draw the land and water on the texture and next display multiple sprites (from top to bottom)

Comment: Oh I did not see you had the unity3d tag, ... well probably some scripting + layers + tiles ...